# How to remove fields from Laravel JSON Api response

Tags: laravel, rest, api, response

I have an API returning an object with one-to-one relation to another object. As the models behind the objects, do have timestamps, these are also delivered when asking API.

```
// Get all transactions
Route::get('transaction', function() {
return Transaction::with('Personone','Persontwo')->get();
});
```

How do I prevent Laravel from returning the timestamps of the objects in the API?

I googled, but only found some hints to middleware or response macros but found no example pointing me into the right direction. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Consider using [a transformer](https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/how-to-start-using-transformers-in-laravel-4ff0158b325f).

Comment: I second the transformer suggestion. They provide a clean abstraction for mapping a model to a response.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? You can use laravel's own transformation if you using laravel 5.4 or greater I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make attributes "hidden" so that they do not show up in json. 
[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['timestamp'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get the question correctly but if you want to select from eager loads there are two ways

first one is inline selecting

```
Route::get('transaction', function () {
    return Transaction::with('Personone:id,foo,bar', 'Persontwo:id,foo,bar,foobar')->get();
});
```

second one is to pass a closure

```
Route::get('transaction', function () {
    return Transaction::with([
        'Personone' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'foo', 'bar');
        },
        'Persontwo' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar');
        }])->get();
});
```

> Eager Loading Specific Columns You may not always need every column
>   from the relationships you are retrieving. For this reason, Eloquent
>   allows you to specify which columns of the relationship you would like
>   to retrieve:
>
> $users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();

> Constraining Eager Loads Sometimes you may wish to eager load a
>   relationship, but also specify additional query constraints for the
>   eager loading query. Here's an example:
>
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>       $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%'); }])->get(); In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts where the post's title
>   column contains the word first. Of course, you may call other query
>   builder methods to further customize the eager loading operation:
>
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>       $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'); }])->get();